# How to get Id of dynamically created buttons in android

Tags: android

I have a number of buttons which are created dynamically, and now I want to change the background of some buttons to be changed depending upon some conditions.

```
Button btn;
Button btn2;

 for(int i=0;i<20;i = i+2) {

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     // LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
     //    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
        params.leftMargin = 10;
        params.rightMargin = 10;
        params.topMargin = 10;
        params.bottomMargin = 10;

        btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(i+1);
        btn.setText( ""+(i+1));
        btn.setBackground(image);
        btn.setTag(i+1);
        buttons.add(btn);
        ids.add(i+1);
        final int index = i;
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("TAG", "The index is" + index);
                String cmd = "";
                if((index+1) >=10) {
                    cmd = createCmd("" + (index + 1));

                }else {
                    cmd = createCmd("0" + (index + 1));

                }
            }
        });

        final int index2 = i+1;
        btn2 = new Button(this);
        btn2.setId(i+2);
        btn2.setText(""+ (i+2));
        btn2.setTag(i+2);
        buttons.add(btn2);
        ids.add(i+2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("TAG", "The index is" + index2);
                String cmd2 = "";
                if((index2+1) >=10){
                    cmd2 = createCmd(""+(index2+1));

                }else {
                    cmd2 = createCmd("0"+(index2+1));

                }
            }
        });

        Log.e(TAG ,"btn.getTag() : "+btn.getTag());
        Log.e(TAG ,"btn.getTag() : "+btn2.getTag());

        btn2.setBackground(image);

        btn.setTextColor( TempSharedPreference.getKeyTextColor(mContext)) ;
        btn2.setTextColor( TempSharedPreference.getKeyTextColor(mContext)) ;
        linearLayout.addView(btn,params);
        linearLayout.addView(btn2,params);


        llDynamicButtons.addView(linearLayout);
    }
```

Comment: simply use `View#setBackground()` method

Comment: Why do you *need* the ID?

Comment: But how can i get view object outside on this method.  I want to do this on different method.

Comment: `private List<Button> buttons` should be a field. You just access it in other method

Comment: can you give me a small code spinet for this. I already added the button in the list. and also the Id as well in another list.   buttons.add(btn2);
        ids.add(i+2);

Comment: you dont need any `ids` list - all you need are `View` references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do something like this with your view group.

```
int count = yourLinearLayout.getChildCount();

View v = null;
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    v = layout.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof Button && v.getTag() == 1/2/3){
       v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff2233"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello dear here is the solution for set and get id of buttons dynamically added in the layout.

Try this one.
Hope this will help you.

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class GetIdDynamicallyAddedContentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Button> buttons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params1);


        buttons = new ArrayList<>();

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setId(i + 1);
            b.setTag(i + 1);
            b.setText("" + (i + 1));
            b.setLayoutParams(params);
            buttons.add(b);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < buttons.size(); j++) {
            layout.addView(buttons.get(j));
        }

        setContentView(layout);
        printIds();
    }

    public void printIds() {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
            if (buttons.get(i).getId() % 2 == 0) {
                buttons.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                buttons.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```